# Even though I am writing different code same problem is shown !! in python

Tags: python, file, null

**File "", line 1, in 
ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
Remainder of file ignored**

````
def guess(x):
    random_number = random.randint(1, x)
    guess= 0
    while guess = input (f'Guess a number beween 1 and %x')
guess(10)```

I am running this code in PyCHarm community edition !! 
Please Help ! 
I am not to find this solution eventhough I tried multiple Sources 
! !
````

Comment: your code is not understandable... please explain what do you want to do

Comment: and it has syntactically error in `while` head, you are not allowed to use `=` in `while` head

Comment: I am just letting My computer guess a number !! 
I am trying this demo from the Freecodecamp channel !!

Comment: `SyntaxError: invalid syntax. Maybe you meant '==' or ':=' instead of '='?` the python error tells you exactly what's wrong ...

Comment: File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes

Remainder of file ignored

Comment: It says exactly this

Answer (score 1):

if you want to computer guess a number, you can use:

```
import random
random.randint(1, 10)
```

or, if you want to get a guess from user:

```
x = 10
input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}')
```

and if you want to computer always guess a number untill it can find user input:

```
import random
def guess(x):
    number = int(input(f'Guess a number between 1 and {x}'))
    while True:
        num = random.randint(1, x)
        print(num)
        if num == number:
            break
guess(10)
```

or, human guess what computer selected:

```
import random
def guess(x):
    number = random.randint(0,x)
    while True:
        user_num = int(input(f"Guess a number between 0 and {x}:"))
        if user_num == number:
            print("You guessed it!")
            break
guess(10)
```